# Why build timestep-unfold LSTM manually has different outputs from using static_rnn?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Here is my code build LSTM manually:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
batch_size = 1
hidden_size = 4
num_steps = 3
input_dim = 5
np.random.seed(123)
input = np.ones([batch_size, num_steps, input_dim], dtype=int)
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_steps, input_dim], name='input_x')
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size)
initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = []
with tf.variable_scope('for_loop', initializer= tf.ones_initializer):
    for i in range(num_steps):
        if i > 0:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        output = lstm_cell(x[:, i, :], initial_state)
        outputs.append(output)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)
    result = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={x: input})
    print(result)
```

The outputs:

```
[(array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32), LSTMStateTuple(c=array([[0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693]], dtype=float32), h=array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32))), 
(array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32), LSTMStateTuple(c=array([[0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693]], dtype=float32), h=array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32))), 
(array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32), LSTMStateTuple(c=array([[0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693, 0.99321693]], dtype=float32), h=array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32)))]
```

While this is the code using static_rnn:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
batch_size = 1
hidden_size = 4
num_steps = 3
input_dim = 5
np.random.seed(123)
input = np.ones([batch_size, num_steps, input_dim], dtype=int)
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_steps, input_dim], name='input_x')
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size)
initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
with tf.variable_scope('static_rnn', initializer= tf.ones_initializer):
    output, state = tf.nn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, y,  initial_state=initial_state)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)
    result = (sess.run([output, state], feed_dict={x: input}))
    print(result)
```

The outputs:

```
[[array([[0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526, 0.7536526]], dtype=float32), 
array([[0.9631945, 0.9631945, 0.9631945, 0.9631945]], dtype=float32), 
array([[0.9948382, 0.9948382, 0.9948382, 0.9948382]], dtype=float32)], LSTMStateTuple(c=array([[2.9925175, 2.9925175, 2.9925175, 2.9925175]], dtype=float32), h=array([[0.9948382, 0.9948382, 0.9948382, 0.9948382]], dtype=float32))]
```

The first cell get exactly equal output, but since the second cell, the manual building seem has no connection with its preceding and succeeding cell --the outputs of the 3 cells are same. I think the manual code is wrong, but I can't find how to connect the BasicLSTMCell s. Help!

Comment: In your loop, you pass the `initial_state` at each timestep. You need to pass the state from the previous timestep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Susmit Agrawal, I change my code as:

```
    for i in range(num_steps):
        if i > 0:
            output = lstm_cell(x[:, i, :], outputs[i-1][1])
        else:
            output = lstm_cell(x[:, i, :], z_state)
        outputs.append(output)
```

This produces correct outputs which is same as static_rnn.